# Nextjs API POST request body not being parsed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've setup a simple api route in nextjs and am trying to parse the body for post request data but get "undefined" when I use the syntax `console.log(req.body.name)`

if I output to the console the request body `console.log(req.body)` I get what looks like a plain string:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMJBujN4oNXLxcU96
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

bilbo.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryMJBujN4oNXLxcU96
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

2995
------WebKitFormBoundaryMJBujN4oNXLxcU96--
```

this is the function:

```
export default (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.status(200).json( { items: [ { req : req.method } ] } )
}
```

and the data in the request headers:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

This question is quite old, but if someone else happens to end up here:

Per the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares):

> req.body - An object containing the body parsed by content-type, or null if no body was sent

This means if you want to parse req.body as JSON you have to set the 'Content-Type': 'application/json' header in the request header:

```
fetch(url, {
    body,
    method,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }),
  })
```